# 0x80005000 AD Bind error after installing .NET 4.0 patches

Tags: .net, bind

We are encountering the following error on Server 2008R2 when attempting to bind to AD:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException(0x80005000) at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIFail) at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() at System.DirectoryServices.Directory.get_Nativeobject()..."

This error ONLY occurs after applying latest patches for .NET 4.0. After receiving the error, we run a repair on .NET 4.0, reboot, and then the application works fine. 
We have a replica of this server in production and do not have this problem. Any ideas?